Issue with Table and Figure Captions Disappearing when Converting AsciiDoc to DOCX using Asciidoctor
I'm encountering an issue when creating captions for tables and figures in AsciiDoc. I’m using :table-caption: and :figure-caption: to automatically generate numbered captions for tables and images in an .adoc file, and I’m working in IntelliJ IDEA.
Here’s an example code:
:figure-caption: Picture
:figure-number:

:table-caption: Table
:table-number:

= Test 1

== Test name table
.Test name table
|===

| Test | Test 2

| Test 3

| Test 4

|===

.Test name table 2
|===

| Test | Test 2

| Test 3

| Test 4

|===

== Test name picture

.Test image
image::diag-plantuml-md5-957b207218bae673e41508d8a99dbda5.png[image]


.Test image 2
image::diag-plantuml-md5-957b207218bae673e41508d8a99dbda5.png[image]

When converting to HTML, the captions display correctly, for example:
Table 1. Test name table
Picture 2. Test image
However, when converting to DOCX format using Asciidoctor, these captions disappear – only the names "Test name table" and "Test image" remain, without the "Table 1." and "Picture 2." parts.
I’m using Asciidoctor for conversion, and Pandoc isn’t an option for this project.
Question: Is there a way to make the captions display correctly when converting to DOCX using Asciidoctor?
Unfortunately, after reading the asciidoctor documentation I have not come to any conclusions about this problem

Can you add the command line you use for the conversion? Which version of asciidoctor are you using?

I used AsciiDoc 0.43.2
Asciidoclet 0.2.0
I do not used command line. I just click the button name "Create DOCX from current file" and my .adoc file convert to docx file.
if you can send me command from line, i would be happy

Asciidoctor doesn't know how to generate DOCX files, which is why I asked how you invoke the conversion. I'm guessing the conversion IntelliJ uses skips the captions.
